# How would you link a number of files (e.g. *.so) by one-liner in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, ln

I need something like

```
ln -s /from/*.so
```

But `ln` doesn't allow such. So how would you do then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

via shell-builtins (and globoperator)

```
from l in /from/*.so; do ln -s "$l"; done
```

via `find`

```
find /from/ -name "*.so" -exec ln -s '{}' ';'
```

doing it via `find` is better since it works better for huge amount of files.

Comment: typo: you mean **for** i guess